# Detecting items in a Dropper

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am standing on a dropper facing upwards, with 64 stone blocks in the top-left slot, and I am running this command:

```
/testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ dropper 1 {Items:[{Count:64,Slot:0,id:stone}]}
```

but for whatever reason, it returns:

```
the block at (coords) does not have the required NBT keys.
```

Answer (score 1):

Count and Slot are both bytes, so need a 'b' after them. You also need to specify the full item name:

```
/testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ dropper 1 {Items:[{Slot:0b,id:minecraft:stone,Count:64b}]}
```